# Why doesn't SSH work if WiFi is on while ethernet is connected?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have two laptops [L1, L2] connected to the same box, both using Debian 11:

- **L1:** connected via ethernet, wireless card on
- **L2:** connected via WiFi only

With this configuration, I can't use SSH to connect L1 [client] to L2 [server], and if I want to use SSH, I have to either disconnect L1's ethernet cable or turn off L1's WiFi, and would like to understand why:

- **Client:**

  ```sh
  ~$ ip -brief addr

    lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
    enp1s0f1         UP             192.168.1.24/24 fe80::id1
    wlp2s0           UP             192.168.1.24/24 fe80::id2
  ```

  ```sh
  ~$ ssh -vvv xxx@192.168.1.21

    OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022

    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *

    debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.1.21 is address
    debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts'
    debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts2'
    debug2: ssh_connect_direct

    debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.21 [192.168.1.21] port 22.
    debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.21 port 22: No route to host

    ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.21 port 22: No route to host
  ```
- **Server:**

  ```sh
  ~# /usr/sbin/sshd -d

    debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_9.2, OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023
    debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa
    debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519

    debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
    debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
    debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000

    debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
    Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
    debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
    Server listening on :: port 22.

    debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
    debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8

    debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_9.2, OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023
    debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:
    debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:
    debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:
    debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3

    Connection from 192.168.1.24 port 36154 on 192.168.1.21 port 22 rdomain ""

    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
    debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
    debug1: permanently_set_uid: 115/65534 [preauth]
    debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT received [preauth]
    debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
    debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
    debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
    debug1: KEX done [preauth]
    debug1: userauth-request for user xxx  service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
    debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
    debug1: PAM: initializing for "xxx"
    debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.1.24"
    debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
    debug1: userauth_send_banner: sent [preauth]
    debug1: userauth-request for user xxx service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]

    debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
    debug1: userauth_pubkey: publickey test pkalg rsa-sha2-512 pkblob RSA SHA256:[preauth]
    debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
    debug1: trying public key file /home/mi/.ssh/authorized_keys
    debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: /home/xxx/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: matching key found: RSA SHA256:
    debug1: /home/xxx/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding

    Accepted key RSA SHA256: found at /home/xxx/.ssh/authorized_keys:1
    debug1: restore_uid: 0/0

    Postponed publickey for xxx from 192.168.1.24 port 36154 ssh2 [preauth]

    debug1: userauth-request for user xxx service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
    debug1: attempt 2 failures 0 [preauth]
    debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
    debug1: trying public key file /home/xxx/.ssh/authorized_keys
    debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: /home/xxx/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: matching key found: RSA SHA256:
    debug1: /home/xxx/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding

    Accepted key RSA SHA256: found at /home/xxx/.ssh/authorized_keys:1

    debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
    debug1: auth_activate_options: setting new authentication options
    debug1: do_pam_account: called

    Accepted publickey for xxx from 192.168.1.24 port 36154 ssh2: RSA SHA256:

    debug1: monitor_child_preauth: user xxx authenticated by privileged process
    debug1: auth_activate_options: setting new authentication options [preauth]
    debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
    debug1: PAM: establishing credentials

    User child is on pid 2553

    debug1: SELinux support disabled
    debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
    debug1: permanently_set_uid: 1000/1000
    debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: ssh_packet_set_postauth: called
    debug1: active: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
    debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
    debug1: server_init_dispatch
    debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 1048576 max 16384
    debug1: input_session_request
    debug1: channel 0: new session [server-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
    debug1: session_new: session 0
    debug1: session_open: channel 0
    debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
    debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
    debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
    debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 1
    debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
    debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
    debug1: Allocating pty.
    debug1: session_new: session 0
    debug1: SELinux support disabled
    debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/1
    debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
    debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
    debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
    debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 1
    debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
    debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell

    Starting session: shell on pts/1 for xxx from 192.168.1.24 port 36154 id 0
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer revised after the question has been updated by the logs and network settings:*

At the client **L1**, both NICs, Ehternet and WiFi have assigned the same IP.
After assigning them different IPs the problem vanished.

---

To get debug logs:

1. Quit any open SSH sessions
2. Stop `sshd`, then restart it with debug verbosity:

   ```bash
   # Get the PID for sshd' and terminate it:
     ps ax | sudo sed -En 's|^\s*([0-9]+)\s.*/usr/sbin/ssh[d].*$|kill \1|pe'

   # Verify success (sshd processes should show up):
     ps ax | grep "ssh[d]"

   # Start sshd with debug option, then print output to screen and file:
     sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d | tee your_debug.log


    # For debug verbosity on the client, call ssh with <-v || -vv || -vvv>:
      # -v: Debug1 || -vv: Debug2 | -vvv: Debug3:
        ssh -v <parameters>
   ```
3. With debugging enabled, `sshd` outputs to the terminal and `your_debug.log`

Comment: "WiFi and Ethernet connects of L1 have their own IP address each" I checked it and it seems that both have the same fixed IP .

Comment: Please issue at L1 `ip -brief addr` and update your question. The debug log for the sshd at L2 is still missing, but is essential. // Interesting is the output `no route to host` .... // Please, when anonymizing, pay attention to change settings synchronous that we can see the real network dependencies and routes.

Comment: See the update and change one of the doubled IPs.

Comment: as soon as the two IP addresses were different the problem disappeared . Now SSH is working alright with both interfaces activated .

Comment: Happy to here that. I updated the answer to current state.